# Getting the line of string from previous pipe output by line number

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

After running the following command, I get:

```
[root@yukiko /]# find / -iname .bashrc
/home/clamav/.bashrc
/home/vpopmail/.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/root/.bashrc
```

But I would like to have a command that prints a specific line by supplying the command with the line number, for example:

```
[root@yukiko /]# find / -iname .bashrc | getline(2)
/home/vpopmail/.bashrc
```

Is there such a command on CentOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a combination of head and tail:

```
find / -iname .bashrc | head -n 2 | tail -n 1
```

this will return the last one row of the first two rows (so the second row). You might be able to get `head` to do the job on its own if it has an option for skipping X number of rows (check `man head`). It is also not unlikely that there is another tool to do the job in the set that is the coretulis package included by most Linux variants so it migth be worth scanning the manual for this group of tools (see http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html or your local copy) a quick scan. It is worth a look anyway if only to refresh yourself on what tools are commonly available.

Answer (score 4):

```
find / -name .bashrc | sed -n '2{p;q}'
```

Comment: +1 for our good friend sed.  With this the OP has the foundation for just what he wants, e.g.:  `getline () { LN=$1; shift; sed -n "${LN}{p;q}" "$@"; }`

Comment: And a +1 for your comment; that's a nice way of hiding sed syntax from those unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whip-up of a Perl script to do that

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings;

my $ln = $ARGV[0];
#note that further evolution may have a regular file here...
my $line = 1; 
my $wantedline;
while(<STDIN>)
{
  $wantedline = $_;
  last if($line++ == $ln);
}
print $wantedline;
```

Comment: Now that's a _lot_ longer than a typical Perl one-liner... `perl -ne 'if($.==2){print;last}'`

Comment: @grawity: That's OK, right?

Comment: It's OK because it is more readable and uses a command line argument instead of hardcoding the number, but it's also not OK because 1) `$wantedline` is completely unneeded and 2) Perl already has a special var `$.` for current line number.

Comment: @grawity: Readability trumps those concerns unless you're skilled in Perl. At least IMO.